# iPhone reports 2 Hotspot connections even though only one of my devices is connected

Tags: iphone, network

I connected to an iPhone Hotspot with a MacBook. I got internet access. Within 15-sec, the iPhone said there was a second Hotspot connection. I toggled Hotspot, reconnected, and still 2 connections. Finally, I turned off Hotspot, changed password, and re-connected the MacBook. A second connection did not happen.

My initial password was not easy to guess `p:Fucrj346Q!`. I've never been in this location before. What could have caused the iPhone to report having 2 connections initially?

**note**: I'm at a hospital where there is an enormous number of magnetic / electrical / radioactive based monitoring equipment.

Comment: I would suggest that you remove your password from the passage for your own security reasons.

Comment: @HarryBeadle That is the old password. No one knew that password, when, or where my Hotspot would pop-up. So "something else" surely must explain the second connection.

Comment: Let me know whether my answer helps or not, just let me know and I'll try to help more!

Comment: i realised that i had my wireless headset connected to itunes account
that is the reason why i was getting the (2 connection)
finally we got the answer. it was so annoying at first to see the 2 connection while having one only.
thanks guyz
i hope now u all can think the same and try to switch off all the connection ur macbook is connecting and then see what you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Other devices (including iPads, iPods, Macs, and other iPhones) connected to the same iCloud account as your iPhone will, if in WiFi range, automatically connect to your iPhone's hotspot when it's turned on ([according to this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18564?locale=en_US) and my personal experience). That means if any of your other devices are lying around, they will automatically connect to your iPhone's hotspot using iCloud.

**tl;dr**: Other devices tied to the same iCloud account might automatically be joining your iPhone's hotspot network.

Comment: My only Apple devices are the MacBook and the iPhone itself. Nobody in range would have known that password. Well, Hotspot now only has one connection, so I don't technically have a problem. But seeing that extra connection pop-up freaked me out. Like I said, I was working in close range to lots of medical equipment, so who knows.

Comment: @imaichiko Well, glad it's gone (probably the equipment?). To be safe, maybe change your iCloud password and set up two-factor authentication for it. And if it ever comes back, just let me know.

Answer (score 8):

I came here because I saw a 3 connections to my iPhone hotspot.
But then checked if just because I was charging through my laptop.
The USB is the 3rd Connection, which disappears as soon as I unplug.

Comment: Agree with Mark's response -- my Mac also showed two connections and it took me forever to figure out that it was the USB plug-in for the phone. If you have something plugged in and you pull the cord(s) out, you should see a connection immediately disappear.

Comment: This was true for me, too - so obvious once you know!

Comment: Thanks @Mark, you solved my mistery! :)
I connect the iPhone over USB for testing my iOS apps and I didn't realize that it counts like one more connection to the personal hotspot!